# Android Chrome background image not rendering

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, background-image

I have an issue where a background image isn't rendering properly on Chrome for Android for the headers of this website.  The site with the issue is at Guinco.steadfastlight.com

The background image itself is being called in inline, with the positioning and repeat and size being defined on the stylesheet.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue right now. Did you ever figure out the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a position: relative seems to have solved this.